# Getting Different Result for AES256Encryption in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

For Encryption using following function:
https://gist.github.com/Veelian/7541502

Whenever I read file in binary and apply encryption on it, 
I get some encrypted text of that file but whenever I execute 
same above operation again then i will get different encrypted text
File is same contents of file also same, still getting different encrypted text
if execute same operation again.

Please find the below code

```
NSString *filePath = @"/Users/xyx/Desktop/NOTICE.txt";
const char *cfilePath = [filePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
FILE *fileStream= fopen (cfilePath,"rb");
NSDictionary *properties = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]       attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
NSNumber *fileSize = [properties objectForKey: NSFileSize];
long l_fileSize = [fileSize longValue];
temp = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*l_fileSize);
fgetpos(fileStream,&pos);
int bytesToRead = (int)l_fileSize;
size_t byt=fread(temp,1,bytesToRead,fileStream);
buffer = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)temp length:sizeof(char)*byt];
NSLog(@"Buffer : %@",buffer);
BytesRead = buffer.length;
NSData *encryptedBytes=[buffer AES256EncryptWithKey:[Security key]]; //taking key from other class
size_t length = [encryptedBytes length] + 1;
unsigned char aBuffer[length];
[encryptedBytes getBytes:aBuffer length:length];
NSString *encBytes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", aBuffer];
NSLog(@"ENcrypted Bytes : %@",encBytes);
```

Comment: Show some code. If the key is the same and the data (file contents) is the same and there are no coding errors the results will be the same. You need to figure out which of the previous assumptions is not correct.

Comment: Using an `NSString` as a key is a bad idea. using a short key and padding it is even worse. Suggestion: Consider using [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor), it includes Password stretching with PBKDF2.

Comment: There are about 12 statements reading the file contents that are unnecessary. More code equates to more changes of bugs. Just read the file into an `NSData`, the code you chose is a category on `NSData`. Best not to use categories.

Comment: @Zaph, "if the key is the same and the data...is the same" and if your encryption scheme is wildly insecure, *then* the results will be the same. The results *should* be different on every encryption. That's a security feature. But the code above *is* wildly insecure (as well as being very over-complicated to recreate `+dataWithContentsOfFile:`), so I don't know why it's returning different values.